# VBA access query, if return is blank how do i skip? and replace

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am doing a query which works fine, when it finds what i am looking for. 98% of the cases.
Sometimes it does not match, and i thought i could do like IfNot Null/Nothing and then just replace the
return value (string)

But that is not working, code below.

```
' The query -> 
Set alarms = alarmDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Data2020 where AlarmCode = " & enteredalarm, dbOpenDynaset)


    If alarms!AlarmText = null Then
        returnAlarm = alarms!AlarmText
    Else
        returnAlarm = "not found"
    End If
```

Instead i get the error,  "Run time error 3021"  record not found.
which makes sense..

I would prefer not to use "on error resume next" etc, so i still have an idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this..

```
If IsNull(alarms!AlarmText) Then
    returnAlarm = "na"
Else
    returnAlarm = alarms!AlarmText
End If
```

Comment: You need to check the `EOF` property of the recordset, e.g. `If alarms.EOF Then returnAlarm = "na" Else ...`.